# Jquery $.getJSON User Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add an html input box to allow users to set a value which adjusts the result returned from a sql request. My request currently contains a parameters to which a variable is supplied and sent as a request.

I am new to jquery and uncertain as to how to fetch the user inputted value as previously done with the simple getElementById in JavaScript.

My jquery is:

```
var schema = 'sewer_pipelines';

        $.getJSON("sql_query.php", // The server URL 
            { parameter: schema },
            saveToArray
            );
```

Is there a method which will allow for user input in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a selector like this :

```
var schema = $('#sewer_piplines').val();
```

More on jquery selectors : https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, problem is now sorted.

Working code is:

```
var schema = $('#attribute_parameter').val();

        $.getJSON("sql_query.php", // The server URL 
            { parameter: schema },
            saveToArray
            );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var value= $('#inputid').val();
```